# Changing between multiple classes with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

I have the following code:

```
<div class="drawing1"></div>    
<button id="start">Begin</button>
```

When the user clicks on the Button, the class assigned to the DIV element should change from drawing1 to drawing5, passing through each drawing in between (There are 5 drawings in total). It should also have a delay() of about 500. My first thought was:

```
$('div').delay(800).toggleClass('drawing1 drawing2');
```

Which works but when I try to add the rest of the drawings (Tried several methods using toggleclass and add/remove class), it either jumps to the last one or only does the second one.

How can I set this up so I can go from one drawing class to the next, going through each one, one by one with the delay applied for each.

Comment: how about chaining both after each other?
and, before someone tells me that it is: Why is this stupid, if so? :)

Comment: What should be animated (you tagged the question '[tag:animation]' after all)?

Comment: `delay()` only works with a queue, specifically the effects queue or a custom queue.  In this case, the delay will not apply, which is why you are seeing it jump to the last class.  You need to use `setTimeout()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var i = 2; //Assumes drawing1 is already applied to the div
var nextDrawing = function(){
    $("div").removeClass()
            .addClass("drawing"+i);

    i = ((i + 1) % 5); //To cycle from 1 to 5
    i = i == 0 ? 5 : i;
}
$('#start').click(function(){
    setInterval(nextDrawing, 500);
});
```

Should do the trick.

Edit: The following modification may be useful to someone for clearing the interval if someone clicks the button more than once.

```
var i = 2; //Assumes drawing1 is already applied to the div
var nextDrawing = function(){
    $("div").removeClass()
            .addClass("drawing"+i);

    i = ((i + 1) % 5); //To cycle from 1 to 5
    i = i == 0 ? 5 : i;
}

var intervalID = undefined;
$('#start').click(function(){
    if( intervalID != undefined )
    {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
    intervalID = setInterval(nextDrawing, 500);
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ajhuU/

Comment: Rather than merely linking to a resource, please, at the *least*, summarise that resource in your answer, and show how it can be used to solve the question to which you're posting an answer.

Comment: Tried to clean it up with better explanation.

Comment: I appreciate that, but that answer doesn't directly solve the question you're answering, unless I'm misunderstanding something. That answer needs to be adapted in some way(s) in order to answer *this* question. If, however, that answer explicitly solved this question, then, for future reference, you should consider [flagging this question](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate of that question (albeit you don't yet have that [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges)).

Comment: Revised it. @David Thomas you were right, my first answer was incorrect. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var leMethod = function(){ // wrapping in a method localizes variables
  var max = 5;             // nr of drawings
  var activeIdx = 0;       // active drawing
  var timeout = 500;       // the time between changes
  var originalClass = 'some classes that are always there';

  setTimeout(function(){               // execute the method on timeout expiration
    var el = $('div');                 // get whatever element you wish to manage
    el.attr('class', originalClass);   // restore original class
    el.addClass('classNr'+activeIdx);  // add your cycle class
    activeIdx = (activeIdx+1) % max;   // update index
  }, timeout);
};

leMethod();
```